# What would be the worst case time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Here's the algorithm:

```
boolean findTripleA(int[] anArray) { 
    if (anArray.length <= 2) { 
        return false; 
    } 

    for (int i=0; i < anArray.length; i++) { 
        // check if anArray[i] occurs at least three times 
        // by counting how often it occurs in anArray 

        int count = 0; 

        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++) { 
            if (anArray[i] == anArray[j]) { 
                count++; 
            } 
        } 

        if (count >= 3) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 

    return false;
}
```

The algorithm is designed to determine whether an array contains at least one number that 
occurs three times or more in the array. My job is to figure out what would be the worst-case for this array, and its time complexity.

My thinking is that the worst case would be if the algorithm had two occurrences of every entry (with the extra entry being unique if the array has an odd number of elements). In this case, the `if` statement within `for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length; j++)` is always violated twice for each pass through the array, forcing the computation to be performed twice, but the algorithm doesn't actually terminate until it has checked every element. I was thinking that this would have a time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Can anyone provide any insight into this one? Because I have a nagging suspicion that I'm incorrect, and if I am I'd like to figure out the correct answer and why it's correct.

Comment: Yep, it is O(n²). Worst case will happen for example when your data has unique values, except the last 3 elements which are the same.

Comment: @Alexandru Barbarosie I was also considering if the last three elements are the same, but then the method would return 'true' when it reaches the second-to-last entry instead of searching all entries. Is this incorrect thinking?

Comment: btw you can do this in O(n) worst-case by iterating once and just making a (hashed) counter of all the numbers you've seen so far.

Comment: @RAF1940 It would still be O(n^2) though (and yes, it would be *slightly* worse to have 2 occurrences all the way).

Comment: @RAF1940 O(n²) - O(1) = O(n²) (where O(1) is constant time for your last computations)

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ This isn't actually my algorithm. I'm just supposed to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking about pure running time, then when the if-statement condition is true comes into play (and then you'd also have to worry about things like branch prediction), but

```
if (anArray[i] == anArray[j]) { 
    count++; 
}
```

takes O(1) time, whether the if-statement condition is true or not. So, for running time *complexity*, the whole function would take O(n<sup>2</sup>). This would happen in any case where either there aren't 3 occurrences, or the first occurrence of an element appearing 3 or more times is near the end ('near the end' may not actually be so near, but let's leave that for another day).

Answer (score 1):

The worst case is O(N^2), and it happens when you don't find a triplet.

Comment: So how many times the if statement is violated is irrelevant?

Comment: @RAF1940 Yes, it's still used a certain number of times.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can violate an if statement... Anyway, you run through the entire array in the outer loop, and then again in the inner one, unless you reach a count>=3.